# Transform type navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

Don't know the best way to explain this so i'll give an example here "http://www.worldinmylens.com/"

I'm trying to replicate the same idea for the aside nav bar in terms of the transition in. I'm not to sure how to go about this properly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.handle').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('showing');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  perspective: 500px;
}
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  opacity: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.showing {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <ol>Home</ol>
        <ol>About</ol>
        <ol>Contact</ol>
        <ol>Blog</ol>
        <ol>Support</ol>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="handle">Click</div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

It kind of works how i want, but i think it has some flaws, can anyone provide an insight how to improve this and work better?

Comment: I can't see what the problem here.

Comment: It doesn't close to the edge properly for one like the demo site when it is closed, it kind of fades out at about 2/3rds of the way.. shouldn't 90deg have it going to a straight line? @MoshFeu, And I'm completely new with transforms/transitions, wondering how this could be done better, my click button also vanishes for some weird reason

Comment: In the example the nav fade out too.. Do you want to change the timing of the fade-out transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

A pro tip: if you want to replicate something that is done elsewhere just open the developer tools of your browser and see how it is done there. Replicating CSS transitions is very easy, just see the styles applied on the target element before and after the transition, and apply these styles on your own element.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var menuOpenButton = document.getElementById("menuOpenButton");
var menuCloseButton = document.getElementById("menuCloseButton");
var menuOpenedClassName = "opened";

menuOpenButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  menu.className += " " + menuOpenedClassName;
}, false);

menuCloseButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  menu.className = menu.className.replace(menuOpenedClassName, "");
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#menuOpenButton {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition-property: transform opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
#menu.opened {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
  color: #cccccc;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;
}
#menuCloseButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuOpenButton"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</div>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menuCloseButton"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
    <li>Menu Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a quick browse and couldn't work it all out tbh so thank's this is great help @smnh

Answer (score 1):

Check this .. i have removed the fade... it may help you

https://fiddle.jshell.net/zLqhndsL/1/

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
margin: 10px auto;

}

.navbar {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 160px;
padding: 20px 10px;
color: white;
background: #333;
opacity: 1;
box-sizing: border-box;
transition:  all  0.6s ease-in;
transform-origin: left;
 }

.handle {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 40px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.showing {

transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(120deg) rotateZ(0deg);
opacity:0.5;
}

<div class="container">
 <nav>

  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <ol>Home</ol>
        <ol>About</ol>
        <ol>Contact</ol>
        <ol>Blog</ol>
        <ol>Support</ol>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </nav>
   </div>
    <div class="handle">Click</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I checked. The problem is that after the transition ended, you can still see the menu in wrong position. You need to hide it eventually.

Comment: no no i didn ask u @MoshFeu. i asked joshuaaron :)))

Comment: is there a way to do this without having it seem like the menu is stretching? Just to be a bit more aesthetically pleasing @Anirudh

Answer (score 1):

Check it here
https://jsfiddle.net/7w2ctxed/

i have removed `nav` tag and button is outside the div.
To make transition in change `transform:rotateY(90deg)` to `transform:rotateY(-90deg)`

```
<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <ol>Home</ol>
        <ol>About</ol>
        <ol>Contact</ol>
        <ol>Blog</ol>
        <ol>Support</ol>
    </ul>
</div>


</div>
<div class="handle">Click</div>
```

css

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
position: relative;
width: 90%;
margin: 20px auto;
perspective: 500px;
}

.navbar {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 180px;
padding: 20px 10px;
color: white;
background: #333;
opacity: 1;
box-sizing: border-box;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
transform-origin: left;
}

.handle {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 40px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.showing {
opacity: 0;
transform: rotateY(90deg) perspective(600px);
}
```

or give `navbar` class to `<nav>` element. like this

https://jsfiddle.net/ouqunnog/

if you want to keep `<nav>`

Comment: This seems good @NafeesAnwar, can you explain how the perspective in the transfrom property affects it as well as having it on the parent element?

Comment: Also is there a way to do this without having it seem like the menu is stretching? @NafeesAnwar

Comment: I didn't notice that. I use to use this method. You can simply remove one of these `perspectives`. It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your rotate is 90 it should be 180. 90 will not close the menu fully.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.handle').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('showing');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  perspective: 500px;
}
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  opacity: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.showing {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <ol>Home</ol>
        <ol>About</ol>
        <ol>Contact</ol>
        <ol>Blog</ol>
        <ol>Support</ol>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="handle">Click</div>
  </nav>
</div>
```